# How to get texture2D of single sprite from single file spritesheet?

Tags: godot, godot4

I have a single file with spritesheets, and I am looking for a way to get a texture2D of a single sprite from the spritesheet programmatically.

Will be really grateful for any tips or ideas!

So far I managed to get an instantiated `Sprite2D` object to display a single sprite from my spritesheet using the following code:

```cs
_dummySprite = new Sprite2D
{
    Texture = heroesSpritesheet,
    Vframes = 13,
    Hframes = 40
};
```

But it only displays a part of the spritesheet, and doesn't crop a texture to the size of a single frame.
Is there a way to get a texture2D of a single frame? I looked into `AtlasTexture` but didn't understand if it is useful for my case.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer that I have been looking for here: [Godot forum](https://forum.godotengine.org/t/how-to-add-frames-from-a-sprite-sheet-in-code/5230/2).
The answer utilizes `AtlasTexture` to "cut out" only the needed part of the sprite sheet. Here is the answer in C#.

```cs
var textureSize = new Vector2(1920, 624);
var spriteSize = new Vector2(48, 48);
var fullSpriteSheet = GD.Load<Texture2D>("res://Assets/SpriteSheet.png");

// in my case I am using hardcoded texture size,
// but it's possible to use spriteSheet.GetHeight()/GetWidth() instead.

var numOfColumns = textureSize.X / spriteSize.X;

var frameTex = new AtlasTexture();
// setting atlas.
frameTex.Atlas = spriteSheet;
// region rect is the single sprite texture that we gonna get.
// It will be the first sprite of the sprite sheet.
frameTex.Region = new Rect2(new Vector2(0, 0), spriteSize);
```

Hope this will be helpful, finding this solution was a little tricky because I did not manage to find many cases of `AtlasTexture` being used.